# Motorola Moto G 2014 freezes on lock screen

Tags: system-freeze, motorola-moto-g2, sleep

Since today I've been having a problem with my Motorola Moto G 2nd Gen(2014). When I boot it up, it works fine for a few minutes (except from the WiFi, which doesn't auto-connect for some reason, happens every time), and then it goes into sleep mode. When I press the power button, the screen turns on again and the lock screen shows up, but it's completely unresponsive. Sometimes it freezes before going into sleep mode and it freezes my home screen. I then get a popup "Google App is not responding" and killing it just gives me an unresponsive black screen.

I've looked the problem up on the internet and I got some answers stating I had to force reboot and that would help, or even wipe the cache partition. I've tried both of those, but the problem persists. What do I do to get my phone fully working again?

Comment: What is your android version? and Did you try factory restoring the device? As you have tried wipe cache partition and rebooting. The next thing you want to try is to soft reset your device. But make sure you backup everything before you do the factory reset.

Comment: @Lucky I'm running Android Lollipop 5.0.2, guess I should have mentioned that. I'm kind of reluctant to try factory reset, as it'll take a while to set up my phone again, but I'll try it, thanks.

Comment: Factory reseting won't take much time. Only the backup stuffs and restoring it takes time. If you don't want to backup any important stuffs then you should be able to do it in 15-30mins  ;) . If you have ideas on backing up your device data, you may want to look into this question on [Full backup of non-rooted devices](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28296/full-backup-of-non-rooted-devices)

Comment: @Lucky I only have to backup internal memory right? As in, I can just remove the SD card while factory resetting? Also, the problem seems to have stopped, suddenly. I've been using my phone with no problem for the past ~20 minutes. Any idea why?

Comment: No most of the app's data will be stored on your internal memory too. So SD card backup isn't the only thing you need to backup. Apps like Camera, Whatsapp will store data in your internal memory as default. So you need to have atleast an `adb backup` of your phone if its unrooted. Couldn't guess about your problem though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I found the solution a while ago and I haven't experienced any problems since, so I guess it works.

I tried different options to get the device working again, but to no avail. The only possibility left was a factory reset, so that's what I had to do. Here's what I did:

1. I made sure the backup settings on my phone were all set up.
2. I used `adb backup` from my computer to make a nearly full device backup, as suggested by Lucky in the comments. More info here: [Full Backup of non-rooted devices](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28296/full-backup-of-non-rooted-devices)

   - For this, make sure you have a password set and configured in the developer settings. This is really important because it might not work otherwise and you'll lose data (happened to me, would not recommend).
3. Then I reset the device. https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/answers/prod_answer_detail/a_id/99825/p/30,6720,9151 for more info how.

It took some time to reconfigure everything and redownload apps, but after a week or so, my device was back to normal and I haven't had any freezes since.